# Passing JButton info from one class to the Main class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have asked a similar question a while ago, so I apologize for asking this if I am abusing the website by doing this, but this question is a bit different. I have a Main class, in which I have created a JFrame, and a JPanel. To avoid clutter, I created another class called "Buttons" to hold all my JButtons. I want to add my JButton to the mainPanel (my JPanel), but I am having trouble inheriting access to the mainPanel from the Button's class.

Here is my Main Class:

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {
    public Main() {
        Main m = new Main();
        //The main window
        JFrame Main = new JFrame("Don't Blink");
        Main.setSize(500,500);
        Main.setResizable(false);
        Main.setVisible(true);
        Main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //The main window's panel
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); //I want to add buttons to this panel from the Buttons class
        mainPanel.setSize(500, 500);
        mainPanel.setVisible(true);
        Main.add(mainPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Main m = new Main();
        }
}
```

The Buttons class:

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Buttons extends Main {
    public Buttons(Main m) {
        //The button to get a job
        JButton workButton = new JButton("Get a job");
        mainPanel.add(workButton);//The mainPanel here gives me
                                      //the error "mainPanel can
                                      //not be resolved". It 
                                      //doesn't seem to recoginze
                                      //mainPanel
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing to call super() in your Buttons constructor. And call a new Buttons instead of a new Main

Comment: [Read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), there's some confusion on your part as far as inheritance. It won't work the way you're trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues here... first of all this is an awful OOP design, but let's see...

You should add as a class variable your mainPanel

```
public class Main extends JPanel {
  JPanel mainPanel;
```

Now to start you don't declare the type, since you want to have it in a class scope:

```
this.mainPanel = new JPanel(); // I want to add buttons to this panel from the Buttons class
```

You are trying to call it in Buttons but you only declared it locally in your Main constructor.

You are calling new Main inside new Main, I believe this will end in an infinite recursion.

remove `Main m = new Main();` from your Main constructor.

I don't think that inherit Main on Buttons is good, but if you really need that, Main does not know about Buttons, anyway you could use the main method in Buttons instead of Main. I'd remove the main method from Main class and add it to Buttons class instead since it is extending Main anyway.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Buttons m = new Buttons();
  }
```

Now, buttons claims to need a Main as argument, that is weird because you want to call the Main, not another Main, I'd remove the argument Main from Buttons constructor. You may think that then you will not have mainPanel but Buttons is already a Main class so it has mainPanel too.

Comment: @user163505 Good, if this answer your question then please accept it so it can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

From an OOP point of view, this is quite bit strange, and does not seem right.

In my opinion, you should not create a separate class for this, just a method, inside the `Main` class, and pass the reference of the panel to it:

```
public class Main extends JPanel{

    public Main(){

        Main m = new Main();

            //The main window
            JFrame Main = new JFrame("Don't Blink");
            Main.setSize(500,500);
            Main.setResizable(false);
            Main.setVisible(true);
            Main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //The main window's panel
            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); //I want to add buttons to this panel from the Buttons class
            mainPanel.setSize(500, 500);
            mainPanel.setVisible(true);
            Main.add(mainPanel);

            addTheButtons(mainPanel); //this does the heavy lifting 
    }

    private addTheButtons(JPanel mainPanel){

        //The button to get a job
        JButton workButton = new JButton("Get a job");
        mainPanel.add(workButton); 

    }
}
```

This would work as long as you don't want to reuse the logic creating the buttons in other classes - but as far as my experience goes with this, this granularity of UI code doen't get reused much...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is bad practice to name a variable name with a capital letter, like Main. Use camelCase.

Please don't use inheritance for this. I recommend you define a method as follows:

```
private Container getButtonContainer() {
    final JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(...);

    ...

    buttonPanel.add(button1);
    buttonPanel.add(button2);

    return buttonPanel;
}
```

Then add this panel to the main panel.